# create a index with a complex json structure using indexeddb

Tags: indexeddb

I want to create an index when i store data using indexeddb.
But I have a structure json like like this:

```
{"query":
        {"page":
               {"4558":
                   {"pageid":4558,"title":"my-title","revisions": [{"user":"dake","timestamp":"54778788585","comment":"#REDIRECT[[Wikipedia:Welcome]]"}]}}}}
```

I just want to create a index which can stores only the value of "title".How can in do?

ObjetStore.createIndex("title","title",{unique:false}) seem does not work.

The number "4558" is dynamic,it's not the same on each record.This tructure is provided by the Wikipedia API that i use to create a webapp.
Thank a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for specically is impossible to do in IndexedDB. IndexedDB does support [key paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB#gloss_keypath) but they consist of one or more fixed identifiers. E.g. `query.page.title` or something would work, but there's no way to allow an arbitrary number to appear inside this path.

You can best convert this data to something more sensible (i.e. something resembling a database record, at the top-level) beforehand. Since IndexedDB supports deep key paths, the id and title of these pages do not have to appear at the top-level of these objects per se, but if your in control of the data, it's good practice to make it so.

Maybe it's enough if you essentially remove the `{"query": {"page": {"4558":` part of the structure. Beyond that, the data looks pretty much ok.